# Trouble Installing GCC on Debian Linux Distribution in Dockerfile

Tags: linux, docker, dockerfile, debian, alpine-linux

I'm currently encountering difficulties while attempting to install the GCC compiler in a Dockerfile specifically when targeting the Debian Linux distribution. Here's the section of my Dockerfile in question:

```
FROM python:3.11.5-bullseye # or python:3.11.5-bookworm

if [-f /etc/os-release ]; then \
    if [ "$ID" == "alpine" ]; then \
       apk update && apk add --no-cache gcc; \
    elif [ "$ID" == "debian" ]; then \
       apt-get update && apt-get install -y gcc; \
    else \
        echo "Unsupported distribution: $ID"; \
        exit 1; \
    fi; \
else \
    echo "Unable to determine the distribution."; \
    exit 1; \
fi; \
```

My goal is to use `apt-get` to install the GCC compiler if the Linux distribution is Debian. However, this code block doesn't appear to correctly recognize the Debian distribution as "debian," resulting in the "Unsupported distribution" error message.

I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to correctly identify the Debian distribution in a Dockerfile and install GCC accordingly. Thank you for your assistance!

Answer (score 1):

"Bookworm" and "bullseye" are both names of [Debian releases](https://www.debian.org/releases/).  If your image name contains either of these, you're all but guaranteed that the underlying image is based on Debian, and it's safe to unconditionally use APT for package installation.

```bash
FROM python:3.11.5-bullseye # or python:3.11.5-bookworm
# without any conditionals or checking on the distribution
RUN apt-get update \
 && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive \
    apt-get install --assume-yes --no-install-recommends \
      gcc
```

(You may want `build-essential` instead, which includes some important support packages like the C header files needed to compile almost anything.)

More generally, the [Docker Hub image page](https://hub.docker.com/_/python) frequently indicates what base Linux distribution a given image is based on.  Changing this can involve close to a total rebuild of an image.  If you discover that for example `python:3.11` currently defaults to a `...-bookworm` image and it's Debian-based, you can probably safely assume that `apt-get` will work, even if the underlying image is updated.

Comment: thanks for the code but I need the if statement because I have different conditions for when there are different releases like alpine and Windows server

Comment: ...but there aren't other cases here.  A `...-bullseye` image will _always_ be Debian and _always_ be Linux.

Comment: I have updated the code for it, my bad I should have at least shown a different distribution as an example